# DAG object has no attribute 'schedule' (Airflow 2.5.0)

Tags: airflow

Using Airflow 2.5.0. I am using a subdag, but imports are working fine:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag import SubDagOperator
from subdags.subdag_downloads import subdag_downloads
 
from datetime import datetime
 
with DAG('group_dag', start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1), 
    schedule='@daily', catchup=False) as dag:

    args = {'start_date':dag.start_date, 
    'schedule':dag.schedule, 
    'catchup':dag.catchup}
 
    downloads = SubDagOperator(
        task_id="downloads",
        subdag=subdag_downloads(dag.dag_id, "downloads", args)
    )
```

This is the error I'm getting when trying to run the DAG in my CLI:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 339, in parse
    loader.exec_module(new_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/group_dag.py", line 12, in <module>
    'schedule':dag.schedule,
AttributeError: 'DAG' object has no attribute 'schedule'
```

As you can see from the code above, I am defining `schedule='@daily'` when I instantiate `with DAG() as dag`, so why can't I access that argument by using `dag.schedule`?

NOTE: I can access the other arguments just fine, such as `dag.catchup` and `dag.start_date`. I can also access the schedule by using `dag.schedule_interval`, but this seems silly and doesn't sit well with me that I don't understand why we can't use `dag.schedule` when `schedule=` is the argument we defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Elad about migrating to [TaskGroup](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#taskgroups) where `SubDagOperator` will be removed in Airflow 3.

But currently, you can access your dag `schedule` by `dag.schedule_interval`:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag import SubDagOperator
from subdags.subdag_downloads import subdag_downloads
 
from datetime import datetime
 
with DAG('group_dag', start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1), 
    schedule='@daily', catchup=False) as dag:

    args = {'start_date':dag.start_date, 
    'schedule':dag.schedule_interval, 
    'catchup':dag.catchup}
 
    downloads = SubDagOperator(
        task_id="downloads",
        subdag=subdag_downloads(dag.dag_id, "downloads", args)
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't access it because there is no such parameter.
While you assign

```
DAG(..., schedule='@daily') as dag:
```

The DAG class does not have `self.schedule`. Airflow accept several kinds of scheduling options and creates from it an internal `scheduling_args` parameter. You can see it in the codebase [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/76186bb58854d851e3599fac3ff9f20feff43bfd/airflow/models/dag.py#L496)

I'd like to point that you are using SubDAG which is a deprecated feature for 2 years. Please migrate to [TaskGroup](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#taskgroups). SubDAGs are not going to stay in Airflow 3.